# What is the future of Class::DBI?

Tags: database, perl, class-dbi

Does anyone know what is the status of Class::DBI? I see that it was last updated on 4 October 2007, is anyone still working on this project or is it just left to die? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Class::DBI collapsed under political pressure and the threats of various lawsuits from one of its developers. It became poisoned code and everyone left. I tried to sort it out in a [post on my O'Reilly weblog](https://web.archive.org/web/20170218074043/http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/will_classdbi_fork.html) back in 2005.

The people who left never really came back. It's mostly legacy code now. If you want to help, there are other active projects that could use your help. In my opinion, Class::DBI is the past and it should stay there. It's unfortunate, but life sucks sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your response I was really curios what happened there and why it was left do die. Sorry for it I guess I just have to do what I tried to avoid.. migrate a huge system from Class::DBI to Class::DBIx.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people seem to use [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBIx::Class) if that helps.

Comment: I know a lot of people just switched to DBIx::Class I was wondering if there's if there is some support or maintenance for the legacy systems.

Answer (score 5):

There are many users of Class::DBI, but no new ones, I guess. Some moved to DBIx::Class::CDBICompat. In general, you can ask in [Class::DBI mailing list](http://lists.digitalcraftsmen.net/mailman/listinfo/classdbi).

If you want, you can help maintain it. Ask where repository is located and start working on bugs in [Class::DBI bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=Class-DBI).